# Is there a command to start logging time on closest parent with previous logs?

Tags: org-mode, logging

Under a "topic" org entry I sometimes make daily sub-entries while working on the topic. Is there a command to start logging time on the top level topic instead of the daily entry?

Comment: Do `C-h f org-clock-in` and see its usage with prefix args. If you invoke it first on the parent with `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-i`, then you can invoke it later on a child with `C-u C-c C-x C-i` and choose `d` (for "default") to start the clock on the parent. Does that work for you?

Comment: @NickD thanks, this does work! The `C-u C-c C-x C-i` shows also a list of recent tasks which was already enough (without even setting a default task). Perhaps you could make your comment an answer so I could check-mark it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Made my comment into an answer]

Do `C-h f org-clock-in` and see its usage with prefix args. If you invoke it first on the parent with `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-i`, then you can invoke it later on a child with `C-u C-c C-x C-i` and choose `d` (for "default") to start the clock on the parent.